# Using boost::asio async model for socket reads, multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I have a case where my app main thread (thread 1) must run unblocked.  It needs to receive streaming data over a socket...and the data will be continuously arriving over time from the remote server.  I have limited control over thread 1 (this is plugin type of software into a larger host application that is providing thread 1).

So, I get called on thread 1 with a pointer to a buffer in which to put the data.  If there is no incoming data from the socket, I can just write zeros.  There needs to be at least X bytes of data to fill the buffer I'm given.  If there is not at least X bytes in the socket buffer (more on this later), then again I can fill it with zeros.

Due to the limited control I have over thread 1, I believe I must have a thread 2 to handle the socket interface (agree?).  Let say I create that thread and set it up much like the boost::asio async TCP [server](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp).  Focusing on the incoming "read" side of this example, consider something like this where I've created an endless "reader" (until I kill io_socket or thread 2 or some such).

```
void do_read()
  {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
        [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t length)
        {
          if (!ec)
          {
            do_read();
          }
        });
  }
```

It is piling data into data_ - a simple static array for the buffer.  Since I don't know exactly how much buffering will be required, I'm considering instead a vector type of implementation.  It seems the boost way to do this is to use the boost::asio::streambuf - which resizes and operates in a FIFO fashion (important because I want my incoming data to stay ordered).  It also has the concept of an input sequence and an output sequence.  My goal is to use this...where thread 2 will be putting data into the output sequence by way of the code above, and thread 1 will be reading data from the input sequence when runs and finds that it has more than X bytes.  The streambuf-internal copy from output to input is done with commit().  But my understanding is that the boost::asio::streambuf is not generally thread safe.  One could wrap all access to the streambuf (either input or output sequence) with a lock to solve the problem, but on the socket side...that lock would have to be held between async_read_some and do_read, because it accesses the streambuf at some point in between.  I think that will be state that thread 2 will be in "most of the time", and so the lock is very limiting on thread 1 (and again thread 1 cannot block so it would have to "try" the lock and rarely get it).

It seems like boost::asio::streambuf should be safe for one thread to access the output sequence while another is accessing the input sequence (?).  I would expect the only point of contention to be commit().  If I had control over commit (and it is not clear that I do...I think possibly async_read does it automatically?) then I could just lock around commit.

Is there any way to do what I am trying to do?  Admittedly, I'm possibly too focused on minimizing copies.  If I allow another copy, then it seems like another thread locked buffer/queue (thread_buf) could be created between thread 1 and 2...where do_read could lock, copy from streambuf to thread_buf, unlock, async_read...etc.  Thread 1 would do lock, if thread_buf has enough data copy it out, unlock.

Comment: Can you make it a little clearer what the question is? Ideally the question would become much shorter

Comment: Taking out all of the justification about why I need to use two threads...you can just read the paragraphs after the code.  I can't come up with anything shorter.  The key question "is there any way to do what I'm trying to do" in third paragraph.

Comment: Sounds awfully like you need to dedicate a worker thread to pumping ASIO's run() loop, and use some form of interprocess communication like futures to push read buffers at the main thread - futures should allow you to avoid almost all explicit locking. Unfortunately ASIO does not permit you to start async ops in a thread concurrent to the one which calls run() without additional locking, this is one of the big things I'm fixing in AFIO v2's shiny new i/o reactor replacing ASIO.

Comment: @Niall - thanks.  I guess I can give up on the dream that streambuf could potentially be used by multiple threads (it would be so awesome)...I'll study futures now.

Comment: Maybe you can try [non_blocking](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/non_blocking/overload3.html) mode, you just call `socket_.read_some` in thread 1, and check whether `error_code == would_block`.

Comment: non_blocking seems to work solidly.  Many thanks - I have something that works well and is simpler than where I was heading, and it has minimal copies.  I kept resolve and connect async as in the boost client async examples, but once connected I just use non-blocking read/write from thread 1.  Very happy...thanks again!

Comment: I'm not sure why the fixation on `streambuf`?? It exists primarily (afaik) for the `read_until` operations. It's an incredible pain the *** to work with actually, especially if you use the `X_until` methods in asio, as the completion handler is often invoked AFTER the condition has been surpassed, so you have more data than you expect in the streambuf and you need to explicitly handle that.